# Sum in closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer.
I am interested in finding a closed form for the sum
$$S(x)=\sum_{j=n}^\infty(n+j)(n+j-1)\cdots(j+1)x^j.$$
If I'm not mistaken, we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty(n+j)(n+j-1)\cdots(j+1)x^j=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$
by differentiating
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$n$ times.

But what about $S(x)$?

Comment: Sum (over j?) range?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) yields
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{n+j}{j} x^j = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$
Your sum is
$$S(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{j=n}^\infty \binom{n+j}{j} x^j = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+j}{j} x^j\right)$$